# How to unset or make condition true, If passed variable is empty or null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query...

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = '$id'
```

if the `$id` is `empty` or `null`, then I need to get all data from table where `id` is `not null`

I already tried like following,

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  table_name 
WHERE
( 
  ('$id' != '' AND id = '$id') 
  OR 
  ('$id' = '' AND id IS NOT NULL)
)
```

But looking for the better solution without `if` condition, because I have lot of `and` conditions

Thanks in advance...

Comment: [Little Bobby](https://xkcd.com/327/) thinks this code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: For NULL you may use `WHERE id = COALESCE($id, id)`. Pay attention - there is no ticks wrapped parameter, they'll convert NULL from "unknown" to definite 4-char string literal.

Comment: @Akina need empty check also...

Comment: If so use `WHERE id = COALESCE(NULLIF($id, ''), id)`. Both NULL and empty string means "return all" in this case.

Comment: @Akina is `$id` needs any quotations...

Comment: I don't know... maybe your `id` has some string type - then, of course, it needs in quotation... but if it is numeric then quotation is excess... and NULL value must NOT be quoted in any case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much @Akina for the comment...

Here is the solution...

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = COALESCE(NULLIF($id, ''), id)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (id = '$id' OR $id IS NULL OR TRIM($id) = '')
```

If `$id` is not null and not empty, then it will be checked against the `id` field.  If `$id` is null or empty, then the filter is ignored and all rows are returned.

**Update**

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (
  (NULLIF(TRIM($id),'') IS NULL AND id IS NOT NULL) OR
  id = $id
)
```

Comment: I need to get all data from table where `id` is `not null` the above query will get all data including `id` is `null`

Comment: if `$id` is empty then what about the `OR id = $id`

Answer (score 0):

You can do trick with `php` itself, like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name where id is not null';

if($id){
   $sql .= ' and id = '.$id;
}
```

Comment: But looking for the better solution without if condition, because I have lot of and conditions